.NET 8 desktop app says that .NET 8 is not installed when it is
I have a C# .NET 8 Windows application that I am building and then trying to run. However, the app won't run as it says .NET 8 isn't installed as shown here:

I have installed the runtime from the link and it still fails.
Looking at the dotnet --info output, it looks like everything is installed:

What else would the app be missing? Or what would prevent it from running?

Does it work when you do dotnet run from the source folder?

No. It produces the same dialog as shown above. This is on a build machine so it has Visual Studio installed on it and it was built on this computer so you would expect it to work.

Can you try deleting the Bin and Obj folders in output folder, get a clean build and run it again? Do you have a problem in debug? Is v8.0.303 SDK is first sdk of this application developed? Thanks for answers to clarify.

Deleted the bin and obj. Rebuilt and it worked fine. Tried running the same command "dotnet publish .\pathto\project.csproj -c Release -r win-x64 --self-contained -o binOutput /nodeReuse:false"
This worked and I could run the app. The times it didn't work was when I was building it through our Jenkins build system. Could this be picking something up incorrectly?
